# A write and a read operation: use one wrlock the two VS a rdlock read operation and a wrlock write operation?

Tags: c++, pthreads

**which is better or faster, A or B?**

```
std::deque<Myclass> queue;
... // do something
std::size_t size = 0;
... // create n threads, one push queue and others pop queue.

// a thread do below
#ifdef A
pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
queue.push_front(myobj);
size = queue.size();
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
#endif

#ifdef B
pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
queue.push_front(myobj); 
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
// if there is some operation,
// I think this B is better,
// because I should get the newest size.
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
size = queue.size();
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
#endif

// other threads do below
pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
queue.pop_back(); 
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
```

**That's my not understanding.**

**Any information or suggestion is great help for me!**

***Apologize for my poor English!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *A* version is faster as you need to acquire the lock only once (you need to acquire the write lock once at any rate).  Also, the returned size will be the *latest* (at the time of *push*) as no other thread can access the queue at the same time.

If you do *B*, you might get a different answer for *size* (as you noted), however, once you release the lock (in either scenarios) the `size` variable can always hold stale value (a thread might have updated the queue by the time you want to *use* the value in `size`)

Also, the readers should query the queue for its size (within the protected section) to avoid an exception if the queue is empty

Comment: Thanks.  I get some info from your helpful answer:  1. "acquire the lock" is heavy (maybe its's syscall of spinlock wrapper?) against several pop or push?  2. No one is better without the actual environment?  About STL, I'm wonder why not directly use the std::deque::size() without lock(it maybe just { return std::dequeue::inner_var_length; }, does it)?  Actually, I'm writing a thread pool, any link or suggestion? Thanks again.

Comment: @HenryLee - accessing a memory location for reading in a threaded environment where a write to the same memory location is possible by other threads is often undefined behavior (though it depends on the threading memory model used)